# Aucune compréhension de cette longue phrase

Tags: sens, philosophie, phrase

Car les hommes d'actions connaissent l'incertitude du destin, la réaction de l'individu au monde, de la volonté au caractère, à l'instant décisif que l'historien ranime lorsqu'il oppose au futur devenu réel les autres éventualités, alors envisagées, aujourd'hui condamnées.

Comment: Les explications de texte ne sont pas permises sur le FSE. Si vous en demandez une, ce qui est le cas dans votre présente requête, votre question sera fermée, personne ne pourra y répondre. Il faut essayer de prendre les choses point par point.

Answer (score 1):

Le texte parle de fatalité.

Voici une tentative de découpage:

```
Car les hommes d'actions connaissent : 
1. l'incertitude du destin  
2. la réaction de l'individu au monde  
3.     //      de la volonté au caractère (?)  
4.     //      [de l'individu] à l'instant décisif que l'historien ranime lorsqu'il oppose au futur devenu réel les autres éventualités alors envisagées aujourd'hui condamnées.
```

On perçoit les prémisses d'une réflexion sur les multivers... ;-)